# Split Payfast payment to two Accounts

Tags: php, html

I am working a Website in which user can register and login, In my website the user can add their arts, products etc.., And the other user can buy the products using payfast payment gatway, the amuont will be received to the product owner.
In this particular commission will be received by the website admin

Here my Problem is now i need to split the payment. that is once a user buying a product, the 80% of the amount will receive by the product owner and 20% will receive by the Admin of the website

Is there any way to split the payment in payfast

Answer (score 0):

I've done a few PayFast integrations and never seen an option to pay multiple accounts at the same time. Also Googling does not show any info on this so short of contacting PayFast I think it's safe to assume it's not possible.

You would have to make the payment go to the website admin and then send 80% to the seller. There are actually a number of benefits to this approach:

- The seller does not need a PayFast account
- The buyer does not have to trust in a random seller
- You can offer the seller additional options
  to receive payment like EFT or PayPal

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely have to split the payment when the products are bought online, your best bet, as a workaround, would be to just have two Payfast accounts.

Then, you'd basically send two payloads to Payfast - one with 80% of the charge, the other with 20%. 
This might be problematic if you have many product owners, or if you add them fairly regularly. I think Mikhail's solution is the best way to go.